# How to "Sync( { alter: true} )" keep data of associations table consistent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize and Node.js I have two models in separate files with an association between them :

File 1:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../db");

const Project = db.define("project", {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  },
  content: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true
  }
});
Project.prototype.associate = (models) => {
    Project.hasMany(models.User);
};
module.exports = Project;
```

File 2:

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../db");

const User = db.define("user", {
  username: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
});
User.prototype.associate = (models) => {
    User.belongsTo(models.Project);
};
module.exports = User;
```

I'm importing those files and creating the connection and `Sync()` the database :

```
const domainsPath = path.join(__dirname, '../../domains');

        //dataBaseConnection is an instance of Sequelize
        fs.readdirSync(domainsPath).forEach(domainFileName => {
            const domain = dataBaseConnection.import(path.join(domainsPath, domainFileName));
            //just adding the objects to a parent return object(dataBase.domains) to use the models later
            dataBase.domains[domain.name] = domain;
        });

        //Executing the associations. I've already tested it, It loads first the Project and then the User
        Object.keys(dataBase.domains).forEach(key => {
            if (dataBase.domains[key].prototype.hasOwnProperty('associate')) {
                dataBase.domains[key].prototype.associate(dataBase.domains);
            }
        });

        //connection Database Sync
        dataBaseConnection.sync({ alter: true}).done((result) => {
            console.log(`${logsColors.FgGreen} DataBase Conected!!!`);
        });
```

I set `{Alter:true}` as I'm in development stage. My relation by default has `onDelete = 'SET NULL'` and when nodemoon restarts my server the `alter:true` drops the source table and sets null on my `projectId` field. If I chance `onDelete` to `CASCADE` it deletes all related registries. How to avoid that?

Comment: Did you think about explicit migrations instead of calling a sync?

Comment: @Anatoly I have, but as I'm still learning sequelize, I want to keep it that way... so I can develop and set up all my final models and data... then I would probably move to Migrations. Is Migrations a quick way to go to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: Migrations take you an ability to control of all database modifications needed by your models. At first you can sync the initial structure, extract the final structure from DB as a script and after time when migrations appear you can just apply them. Another advantage is an ability to have different versions of your app and DB structure.

Comment: So to clarify your question: do you wish theDB structure remains unchanged between restarts?

Comment: @Anatoly The DB structure is basiclly the same but with the `{alter: true}` inside the `.sync()` function, it delete the data of the relations between the columns and models. That is because alter drops the tables and rebuilt them with the dev changes.. but then, I lost track of the registries relationed

Comment: What if you try to explicitly define foreign key columns in models and indicate them in associations?

Comment: The docs says about sync: "Deletes data in columns that were removed or had their type changed in the model".

Comment: I haven't tried putting splicitly the foreign key, I'll try that... I did see that in the docs, but I've seen some unrelated Threads in wich people use to put a `'NO ACTION'` in the association options on the `onDelete` property, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
await sequelize.sync({ alter: { drop: false } });
```

This worked for me.